# Write php if statement dependant on field state in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a product node (Übercart) on which is a custom field with a radio button toggle (For sale/Sold).

I'd like to write a php if statement in my node--product.tpl.php to hide the Übercart Add to cart button and show a sold sign if the radio button field has been toggled to sold.

I have my node--product.tpl.php rendering all the fields but need a conditional statement dependant on the state of the for sale/sold field.

Is this possible? And how?

I've done a var_dump and have the following info related to the  for sale/sold field.

```
["field_product_sold"]=> array(1) { ["und"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(4) "sale" } } }
```

The sold state is sold instead of sale.
I've rendered the add to cart button with this..

```
print render($content['add_to_cart']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as this:

```
if ($node->field_product_sold[$node->language][0]['value'] == 'sale') {
  echo render($content['add_to_cart']);
}
else {
  hide($content['add_to_cart']);
}
```

The `hide()` function will ensure the add to cart form isn't rendered when the rest of `$content` is.